# Rebasing in a shallow clone

Tags: git

How can I reliably perform a rebase when working in a shallow-clone repository? Let's say I have a branch `feature` that I want to rebase onto `master`. How I would do this normally is `git fetch` to update the `master` branch, followed by `git rebase master` to rebase onto it (from the `feature` branch). However, if I understand correctly, it is necessary for the most recent common ancestor of the two branches to be in the history for the rebase to be performed properly.

For example, let's say the full history looks like this:

```
      D-E (master)
     /
A-B-C
     \
      F-G (feature)
```

and I want it to end up like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E (master)-F-G (feature)
```

If I cloned the repository with a depth of 2, then locally the history will look as follows:

```
D-E (master)
F-G (feature)
```

so my plan was to extend the history until there is a common ancestor, which looks as follows:

```
while [ -z $( git merge-base master feature ) ]; do     
    git fetch --deepen=100;
done
```

This is all well and good. However, I sometimes get the issue where my local history will end up looking something like the following (where `*` is to indicate a grafted commit):

```
  D*-E (master)
 /
B*
 \
  F*-G (feature)
```

I don't understand how my local repository ends up being in this state, and if it is in this state, how to get `C` back in the history. The only solution I have found is temporarily making the clone not shallow, but that is very time and space consuming, so I would like to find a better solution.

Note: This is a simplified version of the issue. The exact clone command I am running is `git clone https://... --depth=8 --single-branch`, and according to `git log`, I end up with 28 commits in my history (7 of which are grafted, the first appearing 17 commits ago). This makes no sense to me, as my understanding of the `--depth=` option is that I should end up with 8 commits, the last of which is grafted. Also, my remote does not support the `--deepen=` option on fetches, so I instead use `git fetch depth=$x` with an increasing `x`.

Comment: You definitely should not be missing commits, and re-fetching with a different depth should drop the shallow-graft-snippage from updated commits. What version of Git are you using as a client?

Comment: @torek I'm using 2.26.0. To add to what I said, if I clone with depth 1, I get a log of `G`, depth 2 gets a log of `C-G-G`, 3 gets `C-C-C-G-G-G`, and 4 gets `C-C-C-C-G-G-C-G-C-G`. (where `C` represents a non-grafted commit and `G` is a grafted one, reading most recent to oldest.) I should also note that there is no pattern with merge commits or anything else I could notice.

Comment: Depth refers (or should refer) to graph depth, hence if the top commit is a merge, that first pattern (G, then C plus two Gs) makes sense. If the next step down is another merge, you'd get 8 commits, with the bottom four being shallowed-out (grafted to no parent, by writing the commit's hash into `.git/shallow`). The other parts don't seem right, offhand.

Comment: Also, 2.26.0 is very modern, and should not have lingering bugs from the original shallow implementations, one would hope anyway. :-)